# Не работает привязка для TextBox

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

Делаю TextBox:

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FilterValue}"/>
```

C#:

```
public string FilterValue { get; set; } = "";
```

Когда я меняю FilterValue в коде, то на форме он тоже меняется, но когда ввожу текст в форму, то FilterValue  в коде не обновляется, в чем дело?

P.S. Использую Fody

Comment: Не обновится пока не уйдет фокус на другой контрол. А чтобы "в  режиме реального времени" - нужно в привязку добавить UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс, к свойству которого осуществляется привязка, должен реализовывать интерфейс [INorifyPropertyChanged](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8).

```
public class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private filterValue;
    public string FilterValue
    {
        get
        {
            return filterValue;
        }
        set
        {
             filterValue = value;
             PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FilterValue"));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Если класс, к свойству которого осуществляется привязка, не реализует этот интерфейс, то все привязки будут осуществлены как OneTime. Кроме того, настоятельно рекомендую полностью расписывать привязки, указывая режим явно. В вашем случая я бы использовал такой binding, `{Binding Path=FilterValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}`, более продробно написано [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/11.php)